# How to create a type for object based on enum structure

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a enum as below.

```
export enum Hotkey {
    MARK_IN = 'markIn',
    MARK_OUT = 'markOut',
    GO_TO_MARK_IN = 'goToMarkIn',
    GO_TO_MARK_OUT = 'goToMarkOut'
}
```

Now i want to create a type for a json object that should allow only the keys present in enum but not some random key during development.

```
type hotkey = keyof typeof Hotkey;

type clone = {[key:hotkey]: string}

const finalObject: clone = {
    MARK_IN : 'markIn'
};
```

i created the type as above but that is erroring out when i create the type "clone"

*Error: An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.ts(1337)*

Comment: There is [no such thing as a JSON-'object'](https://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @KooiInc I know it's popular to keep reposting that, but it never sits right with me: a JSON object is an object that can be serialized to/from a JSON string. That definition is fairly intuitive and matches the way people use the term "JSON object" in the common parlance.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a type using an enum for the key this way:

```js
export enum Hotkeys {
  MARK_IN = 'markIn',
  MARK_OUT = 'markOut',
  GO_TO_MARK_IN = 'goToMarkIn',
  GO_TO_MARK_OUT = 'goToMarkOut'
};

type IHotkey = `${ Hotkeys }`;

type IClone = {
  [key in IHotkey]?: string
};
```

If you want to use the enum member as the key you can also do:

```js
const yourObject: IClone = {
  [Hotkeys.MARK_IN] = 'your-value'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Brandon. This was accepting the values in enum as key in my object. 
const finalObject: Iclone = {
    markIn : 'something'
};
But i am expecting the other way round. like 
const finalObject: Iclone = {
    MARK_IN : 'markIn'
};

Comment: @Niranjan I've updated the answer with an example